# add space after the third number except the last four numbers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, and I've a small issue which is that i have column in DB that should store 13 numbers in specific form.
The form is to add space after each 3 numbers except the last four numbers.

For Example:
1234567891234
it should stored in the following format:
123 456 789 1234

Thanks

Comment: Leaving formatting to larvel. If its a number use a number format in mysql. Its searched as a number right? Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

If your column type for this field in your database is numeric you won't be able to store the value with spaces.

That said, to answer your question:

```
$num = 1234567891234;

$iterations = (strlen($num) - 4) / 3;

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    $parts[] = substr($num, $i * 3, 3);
}

$parts[] = substr($num, -4, 4);

$formatted = implode(' ', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value without formatting it and do the formatting on the fly when the value is retrieved from the database. You can achieve it with the following piece of code.

```php
<?php
$str = '1234567891234';
$formatted_no = get_formatted_no($str);
echo $formatted_no;

function get_formatted_no($str){
    $re = '/(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{4})/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    $matches = array_filter($matches, function($key){ return $key; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); 
    return array_reduce($matches, function($accumulator, $item) {
        return $accumulator .= $accumulator ? ' ' . current($item) : current($item); 
    }, '');
}
```

Nevertheless, it's totally up to you, when you wish to do the formatting. You can use the same code above to format the string before storing it in the db so that there's no need to format it every time it's retrieved from the db. Needless to say you will need to change the type of the column in db to `varchar` with this approach.

***I'm even attaching a sandbox link for you to play around***

> [**Live Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/071c87bfeffbdcecaf2500c7d18cbb5f64b52fd6)

Answer (score 0):

If the type is variable string and its length is always 13 then:

```
$number = '1234567891234';    
$numberWithSpace = substr($number, -4);
for ($i = 4; $i < 13; $i+=3) {
    $numberWithSpace = substr($number, -$i, 3) . " " . $numberWithSpace;
}
```